# sql add subtotal and grand total

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, rollup, subtotal

I am trying to add the subtotal of loans and total numbers of weeks by the program and add a grand total for all loans and all weeks at the last row.

I've tried grouping sets and rollup, but the result is unchanged or wrong...

Here is the table:

```
STUDENT (**St_ID**, St_LName, St_FName, Email, Prog_ID@) 
LOCATION **(Location_ID**, Loc_Bldg, Loc_Room) 
ITEM (**Item_ID**, Item_Manuf, Item_Model, Comments1) 
COMPUTER (**Comp_ID**, Comp_Name, Year, Cost, Location_ID@, Item_ID@, Vendor_ID@) 
LOAN (**Loan_ID**, St_ID@, Comp_ID@, Start_Date, Date_Returned) 
PROGRAM (**Prog_ID**, Name) 
VENDOR (**Vendor_ID,** Name, Contact_FName, Contact_LName, Phone, Email)
```

My query and output, but I don't know how to add the subtotal and grand total...

```
select program.Name Prog_Name, student.st_Lname||', '||st_Fname st_name, loan_id, loc_bldg||', '||loc_room location,
           to_char((date_returned-start_date)/7, '99') weeks
    from program right join student using (prog_id)
                 left join loan using (st_id)
                 join computer using (comp_id)
                 join location using (location_id)
    group by grouping sets((program.Name,st_Lname||', '||st_Fname,loan_id, loc_bldg||', '||loc_room, 
    (date_returned-start_date)))
    order by 1,2;



PROG_NAME                      ST_NAME              LOAN_ LOCATION                    WEEKS
------------------------------ -------------------- ----- --------------------------- ----------
Information System             Jiang, Yaohan        0010  Cyert Hall, 0701              0
                               Jiang, Yaohan        0012  Cyert Hall, 0701              2
                               Jiang, Yaohan        0013  Cyert Hall, 0701              6
                               Jiang, Yaohan        0014  Tepper Quad, 1009             7
                               Jiang, Yaohan        0016  Warner Hall, 1304             7
                               Xiao, Shan           0007  Cyert Hall, 0701              9
                               Xu, Sheng            0001  Baker Building, 1101         11
                               Xu, Sheng            0006  Porter Hall, 1004             9
Information Technology         Ouyang, Hsuan        0004  Baker Building, 1101          1
                               Ouyang, Hsuan        0008  Tepper Quad, 1009             5
                               Peng, Bo             0003  Warner Hall, 1304             1
                               Peng, Bo             0015  Warner Hall, 1304
                               Wu, Shinyu           0002  Tepper Quad, 1009             4
                               Wu, Shinyu           0005  Tepper Quad, 1009             0
                               Yin, Abby            0009  Tepper Quad, 1009             1
```

Comment: I am using Oracle, and I also add “break on prog_name” in Oracle, so the table will not repeat the program_name

Comment: You might be able to get subtotal and total using statistical functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a) your grouping sets aren't correct, and b) you don't have any aggregate functions to do the grouping sets against.

I think the following is what you're after:

```
WITH your_results AS (SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Jiang, Yaohan' st_name, 10 loan, 'Cyert Hall, 0701' LOCATION, 0 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Jiang, Yaohan' st_name, 12 loan, 'Cyert Hall, 0701' LOCATION, 2 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Jiang, Yaohan' st_name, 13 loan, 'Cyert Hall, 0701' LOCATION, 6 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Jiang, Yaohan' st_name, 14 loan, 'Tepper Quad, 1009' LOCATION, 7 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Jiang, Yaohan' st_name, 16 loan, 'Warner Hall, 1304' LOCATION, 7 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Xiao, Shan' st_name, 7 loan, 'Cyert Hall, 0701' LOCATION, 9 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Xu, Sheng' st_name, 1 loan, 'Baker Building, 1101' LOCATION, 11 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information System' prog_name, 'Xu, Sheng' st_name, 6 loan, 'Porter Hall, 1004' LOCATION, 9 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Ouyang, Hsuan' st_name, 4 loan, 'Baker Building, 1101' LOCATION, 1 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Ouyang, Hsuan' st_name, 8 loan, 'Tepper Quad' LOCATION, 5 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Peng, Bo' st_name, 3 loan, 'Warner Hall, 1304' LOCATION, 1 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Peng, Bo' st_name, 15 loan, 'Warner Hall, 1304' LOCATION, NULL weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Wu, Shinyu' st_name, 2 loan, 'Tepper Quad' LOCATION, 4 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Wu, Shinyu' st_name, 5 loan, 'Tepper Quad' LOCATION, 0 weeks FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Information Technology' prog_name, 'Yin, Abby' st_name, 9 loan, 'Tepper Quad' LOCATION, 1 weeks FROM dual)
SELECT prog_name,
       st_name,
       sum(loan) loan,
       LOCATION,
       sum(weeks) weeks
FROM   your_results
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((prog_name, st_name, loan, location, weeks), (prog_name), ())
ORDER BY prog_name, st_name, weeks;

PROG_NAME              ST_NAME             LOAN LOCATION                  WEEKS
---------------------- ------------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
Information System     Jiang, Yaohan         10 Cyert Hall, 0701              0
Information System     Jiang, Yaohan         12 Cyert Hall, 0701              2
Information System     Jiang, Yaohan         13 Cyert Hall, 0701              6
Information System     Jiang, Yaohan         14 Tepper Quad, 1009             7
Information System     Jiang, Yaohan         16 Warner Hall, 1304             7
Information System     Xiao, Shan             7 Cyert Hall, 0701              9
Information System     Xu, Sheng              6 Porter Hall, 1004             9
Information System     Xu, Sheng              1 Baker Building, 1101         11
Information System                           79                              51
Information Technology Ouyang, Hsuan          4 Baker Building, 1101          1
Information Technology Ouyang, Hsuan          8 Tepper Quad, 1009             5
Information Technology Peng, Bo               3 Warner Hall, 1304             1
Information Technology Peng, Bo              15 Warner Hall, 1304    
Information Technology Wu, Shinyu             5 Tepper Quad, 1009             0
Information Technology Wu, Shinyu             2 Tepper Quad, 1009             4
Information Technology Yin, Abby              9 Tepper Quad, 1009             1
Information Technology                       46                              12
                                            125                              63
```

(You would replace the your_results subquery with the query that returns the data you're trying to group against.)

This has the advantage of not requiring SQL*Plus features (break, compute).

If you still only want to output the prog_name for the first row without using SQL*Plus features, you would do:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN pn END prog_name,
       st_name,
       loan,
       LOCATION,
       weeks
FROM   (SELECT prog_name pn,
               st_name,
               sum(loan) loan,
               LOCATION,
               sum(weeks) weeks,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY prog_name ORDER BY st_name, weeks, LOCATION) rn
        FROM   your_results
        GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((prog_name, st_name, loan, location, weeks), (prog_name), ()))
ORDER BY pn, st_name, weeks, LOCATION;
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I successful grouping the data, but I don't understand why there is no subtotal in the result... I indeed add one () in grouping sets : grouping sets((...),(...), ())

Comment: What do you mean, no subtotal in the result? There are subtotals in my results?

Comment: Oh! I found the reason,  in my query I used to_char for weeks, so it cannot add subtotal :P

Answer (score 1):

It isn't enough to *break* - you have to actually *compute* sum of some column. Here's an example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> break on report on deptno
SQL> compute sum of sal on deptno
SQL> compute sum of sal on report
SQL>
SQL> select deptno, ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
           KING       PRESIDENT      10000
           MILLER     CLERK           1300
**********                      ----------
sum                                  13750
        20 JONES      MANAGER         2975
           FORD       ANALYST         3000
           ADAMS      CLERK           1100
           SMITH      CLERK            920
           SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
**********                      ----------
sum                                  10995
        30 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
           TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
           ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
           JAMES      CLERK            950
           BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
           MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
**********                      ----------
sum                                   9400
                                ----------
sum                                  34145

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please get the reference from the below example. Hope it will solve your problem**

```
Table: Earning

    Name    Monthly_Earning  Month
    ---------------------------------
    A       1000            January
    A       1500            January
    B       2400            Febuary
    A       1500            Febuary
    B       2100            January
    B       1100            Febuary
    A       4000            Febuary
    B       8000            January

 select Name,Monthly_Earning,Month from (
select Name,Monthly_Earning,Month from Earning e1 
union all 
select 'subtotal',sum(e2.Monthly_Earning), month from Earning e2 group by Month
union all 
select 'subtotal',sum(e2.Monthly_Earning), month from Earning e3
) e4
order by e4.Month, e4.Name
```

Comment: That would be quite inefficient; you're accessing the same table 3 times. That's OK (kind of) for a small data set, but mind millions of rows ... Performance would suffer.